# How to find number of clusters in a image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

Find the number of clusters in this image:

[image]
I'm trying to find the number of cluster in this image. I tried openCV morphologyEx and erode but can't seem to get a single pixel for each cluster. Please suggest which would be the best way to count the number of clusters in an image using openCV preferably in Python.

**--Edit**

I tried thinning, erode and morphologyEx(closing) but couldn't converge the clusters to a single pixel. Below are some of things I tried.

```
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8) #[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]
erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('test1.jpg', erosion)
cv2.imwrite('test2.jpg', closing)

img = cv2.imread(file, 0)
size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

#ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
done = False

while (not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img, element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded, element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img, temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel, temp)
    img = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros == size:
        done = True

cv2.imwrite('thinning.jpg', skel)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Generally it is advisable to put in a a code sample of your attempt at the problem

Comment: Could you please add an image to your question in order to allow the reader to have a better understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is as simple as this. You should find number of contours of the image and count them. For that you can use `cv2.findContours` method with following parameters. For further details about `cv2.findContours` please check the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html).

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)

image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
count = len(contours)
print(count)
```

**output:**

```
973
```

Comment: Is there a best way to segment them into rows and columns as well?

Comment: Yes, come up with a proper question

Answer (score 4):

How is this?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('points.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

n_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh)

print(n_labels)

size_thresh = 1
for i in range(1, n_labels):
    if stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] >= size_thresh:
        #print(stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
        x = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
        y = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
        w = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
        h = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), thickness=1)

cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", img)
```

number of cluster : 974
out.jpg :
[image]

Comment: Is there a best way to segment them into rows and columns as well?